# How to retrieve rows from table A whose VARCHAR column has a partial match on another VARCHAR col. in table B?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

MySQL: 5.6

I have 2 tables - one has a VARCHAR column containing email addresses, and the other has a VARCHAR column with domain names.

Sample email address: john@yahoo.co.uk
Sample domain name: yahoo.co.uk

I need to retrieve the list of email addresses that belong to domains that are in the domains table.

How can I accomplish this most efficiently?

Thanks in advance for any responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LIKE` on this. (*use for string matching*)

But the problem with using `LIKE` is that it doesn't use any index that is provided on the column. This will likely to perform better on database with smaller records but on big database that already contains thousands of records it will have poor in performance. The reason for that is because it will do `FULL TABLE SCAN` that runs on every record on the table which is very slow.

```
SELECT  a.DomainName, b.EmailAdd
FROM    DomainList a
        INNER JOIN EmailList b
          ON b.EmailAdd LIKE CONCAT('%', a.DomainName)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/730ee/1)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to `JOIN` on both tables and uses `LIKE` with `CONCAT`:

```
SELECT D.Domain, E.Email
FROM Domains D
   JOIN Emails E ON E.Email LIKE CONCAT('%',D.Domain)
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f08e9/1)

Comment: Its the same answer as JW posted, but since he added explanation about the performance downsides, I will accept his answer.